# Can i install ubuntu in a usb drive while my computer is a windows 7 32bit that has 2gb ram

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 22.04, windows-7

I want to install ubuntu's latest version in a usb drive following this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), can i install it in my windows 7 32bit os that have 2gb ram? if yes please tell me how.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking, you mention the *latest version of Ubuntu* but gave no specifics as to if you're asking about Ubuntu Server 23.10 or Ubuntu Desktop 23.10. I still have a device with only 2GB of RAM that I've used in all releases of Ubuntu, but I'd personally opt for a *lighter* flavor of Ubuntu than Ubuntu Desktop on my an core2duo laptop; but you maybe asking about a server (text only/non-GUI) Ubuntu install as you don't specify.  Have you tried running it *live*, as it's what I'd do first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: As for *Try before Install* I'll suggest https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  but please note it can be used for all Ubuntu Desktop *flavors* too.. Being specific as to what Ubuntu 23.10 (ie. *latest* release) you're after would help, why tag 22.04 as that is **not** the latest release, being four releases ago!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)